# Expose VNC port when building via VMWare Workstation

Tags: vmware, vnc, vmware-workstation

I am performing a remote headless build on a Ubuntu 16.04.05 server using `packer`.

When the build starts, I get the informative message

```
vmware-iso: The VM will be run headless, without a GUI. If you want to
vmware-iso: view the screen of the VM, connect via VNC with the password "somepass" to
vmware-iso: vnc://127.0.0.1:5914
```

However when trying using a [vncviewer](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/linux/) to access this remotely by accessing :5914 I get a connection refused error;

What is more,

```
$ nc -zv <my_host_name> 5914
nc: connect to <my_host_name> port 5914 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

Any suggestions?

**edit**: It seems that VMWare is somehow configured so that its VNCServer (?) listens only on `localhost`:

```
pkaramol@<my_host_name> :~/.vmware$ sudo ss -l | grep 5904
tcp    LISTEN     0      5      127.0.0.1:5904                  *:*
```

Answer (score 0):

If SSH is available on your host, you can try using VNC with a secure tunnel to your client:

```
<client> $ sudo ssh -C -L 9999:localhost:5904 pkaramol@<my_host_name_or_ip>
<client> $ vncviewer localhost::9999
```

Depending on your setup, you may not need sudo or the the -C (compression) option. Also you can replace 9999 by a port you like.

PS: Sorry, but without right to comment I was not able to clarify.